# Waiting for external dependencies in dask

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

**Context:**
I'm using custom [dask](https://dask.org/) graphs to manage and distribute computations.

**Problem:**
Some tasks include reading in files which are produced outside of dask and not necessarily available at the time of calling `dask.get(graph,result_key)`.

**Question:**
Having the i/o tasks wait for files is not an option as this would block workers. Is there (or which would be) a good way to let dask wait for the files to become available and only then execute the i/o tasks?

Thanks a lot for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use some of the more real-time features of Dask, described [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html).

You might consider making tasks that use [secede](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.secede) and [rejoin](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.rejoin) or use async-await style programming and only launch tasks once your client process notices that they exist.

Comment: Great, I didn't know this functionality. Basically the task waiting for the file would contain `secede()`, a waiting loop and then `rejoin()`. If I understand correctly, this makes the task wait for the file in an administrative thread, thereby not blocking the worker's thread pool. Thanks!